# Python - Create new log files after interval of 10 minutes

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I want to set up a new log file after a certain interval of suppose say 10 minutes and all the logs should go in the new log file.

I am having logger.py defined like this -

```
import logging
import os


class Logger():
    loggers = {}
    logger = None
    def getlogger(self,name):
        file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(module)s : %(funcName)s] : %('
                                           'message)s')

        console_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(levelname)s -- %(message)s')
        print(os.getcwd())
        file_name = "src/logs/"+name+".log"
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(file_name)
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        file_handler.setFormatter(file_formatter)

        logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        logger.propagate = False
        self.loggers[name] = logger

        return logger


    def getCommonLogger(self):
        if self.loggers.get("dashboard_asset_logs"):
            return self.loggers.get("dashboard_asset_logs")
        else:
            self.logger = self.getlogger("dashboard_asset_logs")
        return self.logger
```

I am having the app.py defined like this

```
from src.main import logger


logger_obj = logger.Logger()
logger = logger_obj.getCommonLogger()


def log_trial():
    logger.info("----------Log - start ---------------------")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    log_trial()
```

I am running the code like this `python -m src.main.app`

Can anyone tell how can the logs go to files like dashboard_asset_logs and then another file after every interval of 10 minutes?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler and below.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. This documentation is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler), for example

```py
import logging.handlers
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(
    filename=file_name,
    when="M",
    interval=10,
)
```

That handler will rotate the log file every 10 minutes.